# Possible to covert normal switch to three way?

Tags: electrical, switch, dimmer-switch, multiway-switch

I'm in the middle of a home renovation project (not doing it myself) and I purchased some nice brass light switches for my office. There are two places in the room where we have switches and they are on three way with each one. One bank of switches are toggles and the other bank are dimmer knobs. The problem is that the dimmer knobs are not set up to be three way and I didn't realize this until I the electrician tried to install them. Unfortunately the maker of the switch doesn't have a three way version. I'd really like to use these switches so I'm trying to figure out a way to do that. Is it possible to modify a normal dimmer switch to work as a three way switch? Obviously I would hire someone to do this and not attempt it myself, I just want to know if that's a possibility.

Comment: Why not just get three way dimmers?  You can't change a simple switch to three way.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the switch maker doesn't do a three way dimmer.

Comment: Find one that does.

Comment: _Possible?_ Yes, but you'd have to open the switches, replace the internals, add another wiring point to the outside and _COMPLETELY_ void the UL listing. If your electrician is even the slightest bit competent, he would absolutely _refuse_ to install this home brewed abomination (or risk loosing his license). When the house burns down, your insurance company would deny your claim. _Recommended?_ No.

Comment: Who the heck made your dimmers anyway?

Comment: Maybe I came to the wrong place for advice

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to modify a normal dimmer switch to work as a three way
> switch?

It is not possible.  The difference between 2-way, 3-way, and 4-way switches is inherent to the internal design of the switch.

Answer (score 2):

If you have neutral at both switch boxes, another solution is smart dimmers with one just set up to act as a remote control for the other.

Comment: Thank you for offering an actually constructive solution!